# jquery: animate.step change direction

Tags: jquery, html, svg, jquery-animate

i'm having an inline svg with a rect-element. Now I want to change the size of the rect-element using jquery:

```
function rect1() {
$("#rect1").animate(
   {"foo":200},
   { 
        step: function(foo){
              $(this).attr("height",foo);
        },
        duration: 2000
   }
)};

<svg height="100%" width="100%" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 628 400">
   <rect id="kom1" stroke="#fc0" y="200" x="200" width="100px" height="100px" fill="#fc0"/>
</svg>
```

It works pretty well, the only problem so far: the rect-element will "grow" to the bottom.

How can I change this behaviour so the rect-element will grow to the top?

Thanks
Ivan

Comment: change the y at the same time as the height but in the opposite direction.

Comment: @RobertLongson I dont get it. How should I change the y of the rect?